# javascript check if image exists iOS app

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, ios, file

I am building a simple app for the iPad. As it is easier, I decided to go with HTML and a little bit of JavaScript, but I have hit a wall. How I can check in JavaScript if an image (local image) exists?

Comment: Please do not create an iPad app that's really just an HTML site inside a `UIWebView`. It will suck.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful  http://www.irt.org/script/52.htm